# Dealing with SQL server datetime edge cases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2000

I have the following data in a SQL Server 2000 table:

```
Dates
-----------------------
2012-05-04 01:23:45.678
2012-05-05 01:23:45.678
2012-05-06 01:23:45.678
```

Suppose `GETDATE()` returns:

```
2012-05-05 12:34:56.789
```

I need the most efficient (and elegant) query that returns rows #2 and #3 from above, the criteria being:

> date portion of **Dates** >= date portion of **GETDATE()**

Comment: Correlated to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353014/convert-sql-server-datetime-fields-to-compare-date-parts-only-with-indexed-look

Comment: @Oded: `WHERE CONVERT( VARCHAR, Dates, 101 ) >= GETDATE( ) - 1` (i) it does not use any indexes (ii) it fails on edge case when time portion for `GETDATE()` is exactly `00:00:00`.

Comment: Start off by "caching" `GETDATE()` (or the exact value you need - without the time portion) in a local variable.

Comment: And you only need to compare the _whole_ date to the current date in order to get that value. Converting to a VARCHAR kills indexing - it is not sargable.

Comment: @Oded: I convert it to a varchar to eliminate the time portion (it is the only way I know).

Comment: @SalmanA - It is not a good way when used in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME
SELECT @Now = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT ...
WHERE Dates >= @Now
```

Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177529/1583) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353049/1583).