# How do I group by date and not have the time being a factor?

Tags: sql, datetime

My DateCompleted return the date and the time. If I would like to group just by the date and ignore the time. How would I go about this?

```
SELECT  
  Cast(Jobs.DateCompleted AS VarChar) AS 'DateCompleted',
  SUM(Metrics.GB) AS GB, 
  SUM(Metrics.KB) AS KB
FROM Metrics 
INNER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.JobId = Metrics.JobId 
INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects.ProjectId = Jobs.ProjectId 
INNER JOIN JobTypes ON JobTypes.JobTypeId = Jobs.JobTypeId
WHERE Jobs.DateCompleted BETWEEN '12/01/2012' AND '12/03/2012' 
GROUP BY Jobs.DateCompleted
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, then you can convert the value as a `varchar` with a format that strips the time:

```
SELECT convert(char(10), Jobs.DateCompleted, 120) AS DateCompleted,
  SUM(Metrics.GB) AS GB, 
  SUM(Metrics.KB) AS KB
FROM Metrics 
INNER JOIN Jobs 
  ON Jobs.JobId = Metrics.JobId 
INNER JOIN Projects 
  ON Projects.ProjectId = Jobs.ProjectId 
INNER JOIN JobTypes 
  ON JobTypes.JobTypeId = Jobs.JobTypeId
WHERE Jobs.DateCompleted Between '12/01/2012' AND '12/03/2012' 
GROUP BY convert(char(10), Jobs.DateCompleted, 120)
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can cast the value as a date:

```
SELECT cast(Jobs.DateCompleted as date) AS DateCompleted,
  SUM(Metrics.GB) AS GB, 
  SUM(Metrics.KB) AS KB
FROM Metrics 
INNER JOIN Jobs 
  ON Jobs.JobId = Metrics.JobId 
INNER JOIN Projects 
  ON Projects.ProjectId = Jobs.ProjectId 
INNER JOIN JobTypes 
  ON JobTypes.JobTypeId = Jobs.JobTypeId
WHERE Jobs.DateCompleted Between '12/01/2012' AND '12/03/2012' 
GROUP BY cast(Jobs.DateCompleted as date)
```

*Note: I am assuming SQL Server based on your previous tags*

Answer (score 0):

Write an expression that Strips off the time portion, and group by this expression... In Ms SQL Server you can use `DateAdd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, myDatetime), 0)`  Each RDBMS has its own functions or syntax for this.  for Ms SQLServer see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353014/convert-sql-server-datetime-fields-to-compare-date-parts-only-with-indexed-look/353049#353049)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you convert the datetime to a date, either explicitly (if date is a supported data type) or implicitly (to a string).

The ANSI standard way is to do something like:

```
select extract(year from jobs.DateCompleted),
       extract(month from jobs.DateCompleted),
       extract(day from jobs.DateCompleted),
. . .
group by extract(year from jobs.DateCompleted),
       extract(month from jobs.DateCompleted),
       extract(day from jobs.DateCompleted)
```

But no on ever does that.  In recent versions of SQL Server, you would use `cast(jobs.DateCompleted as date)`.  In MySQL, `date(jobs.DateCompleted)`.  In Oracle, I would do `to_char(jobs.DateCompleted, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a rdbms, so here's a wild guess.

If you are using SQL Server, then you can group by `datepart` parts of your datetimes.

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Jobs.DateCompleted),
         DATEPART(month, Jobs.DateCompleted),
         DATEPART(day, Jobs.DateCompleted)
```