# Fetching Records from the Table Based on specific Time Interval for the Same Date in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with column Date and time together (Say Created Date). I have a requirement to fetch records from the Table by passing the time alone(since I retrieve the records at different intervals in same date).

My question is how do I break the time part alone in DateTime field in my Table while  Fetching the records using Stored procedure

Further to Quote an example
I have to fetch data from the same table for
5 times in a specified date
say

```
9.00 to 10.00
11.00 to 12.00
....
....
13.00 to 14.00 etc
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: [consider this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353049/1132334), old but still valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was very simple and can be done in very optimize and SARGABLE way.

```
Declare @input datetime='2018-09-04'

declare @starttime varchar(15)='13:00'
declare @endtime varchar(15)='14:00'

declare @StartDate datetime=@input+@starttime

declare @EndDate datetime=@input+@endtime

select * from 
table1 
where createdate>=@StartDate and createdate<=@EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `datepart()` function to just extract the hour:

```
select datepart(hour, createdat), . . .
from . . .
where datepart(hour, createdat) between 9 and 13
group by datepart(hour, createdat)
order by datepart(hour, createdat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break Time part from DateTime field Using of below code.

```
select cast(CreatedDate as time) as TimePart
from your_Table_name
```